# Best way to uninstall; backup programs on Mac

Tags: mac, backup, macos

Macbook laptop has a few programs .. in which I'd like to uninstall 
and then keep the programs on a disc or external hd.

Should I clone the program? (best suggested freeware? eg. Clonezilla or ..) 
or use a software such as Time Machine or Carbon Copy Cloner?

What are other best tips on speeding up Mac OS settings? (tuning particular features, functions on control panel?)

Comment: For the programs, you will be having the dmg. Backup the dmg instead of programs

Comment: It is not clear why you'd want to backup the program. Do you want to backup your current settings as well? How is speeding up OS X connected to that?

Comment: So backup dmg along with related files in the apps folder is best suggested? Is there also a best complete uninstall program to use or the mac default is sufficient? My speeding up mac is a side note question, just good to have a fast mac in working with. In choosing a free backup program, are there best preferences or suggestions? Carbon copy cleaner, time machine?

Comment: Make the speeding up a separate question and remove it here, please.

Comment: The backup part should also be made a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall programs, just delete them.

To back them up, the best idea is to keep the installer. In most cases, this is the .dmg the app came in. If it came from the App Store, there's nothing to keep. Other programs can come with installer packages (.pkg) or apps; these are what you'd keep in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Simply "trashing" apps from the Applications directory can leave behind little files all over your system.  For complete installation, there are several apps that can find and remove the accompanying "helper" files.

Two of the more popular options are...

- [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/) ($13) -- very simple, best interface
- [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/index.php) (free) -- free version of above

There is also an app called [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) ($22, free trial available) that can "watch" your Applications folder, and offer to delete the helper files when an app gets trashed.  (Probably not worth it for the "uninstall" feature alone, but it also automatically organizes my Downloads folder and keeps my desktop clean.)

Answer (score -1):

If the already installed programs are not useful for you from future P.O.V., then simply uninstall them from your Mac hard drive. It will also improve the Mac performance significantly by freeing up the Mac hard drive space.

Also, both CloneZilla and Time Machine are free programs, and you can use any one of them as per your requirements. However, sometimes using these free program can results in un-necessary data loss problems (that is why I avoid free programs).